# Magento 2 backend customer grid empty

Tags: magento2

I have migrated from Magento 1.x to Magento 2. Everything is working except that there are no customers displayed in the backend. I thought it might be some attribute that is loaded and nonexisting in my new installation, so I logged all SQL statements, but to problem is that there is no query that contains `customer` at all. If I click on the customer edit link on an order, it displays the customer edit page correctly. What could cause this problem and where can I start to dig deeper into this problem?

There are no errors logged and no (uncaught) exception occures. I also reindexed everything and cleared all caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by truncating the table `customer_visitor`. The problem was that the query took too long because of very much data in this table.

Answer (score 12):

This is a problem with the reindexing process.
Solve it by running the following command in MySQL:

```
update magento.indexer_state set status='invalid' where status ='working'
```

Afterwards, run the indexer process in the console with the following command in your magento directory:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Your customers will now appear as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Below command.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset && php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that indexer had a problems with certain PHP 7 version. If you are using PHP 7, can you maybe switch to PHP 5.6 ?

Comment: And maybe recheck your Crons, I had similar problem, but then I used whole php path and included php.ini in cron, as specified in Magento documentation and magicly reindexing started to work.